# How to calculate sum of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I want to calculate sum of array data in JavaScript.

Array **:**

```
[
  {
    red_team: {
      count: 2,
      money: 3000,
    },
    blue_team: {
      count: 10,
      money: 100000,
    },
  },
  {
    red_team: {
      count: 1,
      money: 1000,
    },
    blue_team: {
      count: 100,
      money: 200000,
    },
  }
]
```

Expected Result **:**

```
{
  red_team: {
    count: 3,
    money: 4000,
  },
  blue_team: {
    count: 110,
    money: 300000,
  },
}
```

**Note :** `red_team` & `blue_team` is an Enum.

how can I calculate it ?

Comment: Please share your attempt(s) so far

Comment: There are many ways to do this. But first you should attempt to figure it out yourself. That is the best way to learn. Start out by looping through the array and keep a value for red_team and a value for blue_team

Comment: Do you know the amount of objects there are in the array (e.g. since this is a game, do you know the amount of rounds beforehand)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spread the array into lodash's `_.mergeWith()`, and create a customizer that sums number, but returns `undefined` for all other types, so that lodash would handle all other cases:

```js
const data = [{"red_team":{"count":2,"money":3000},"blue_team":{"count":10,"money":100000}},{"red_team":{"count":1,"money":1000},"blue_team":{"count":100,"money":200000}}]


const result = _.mergeWith({}, ...data, (a, b) => 
  _.isNumber(a) ? a + b : undefined
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per a comment above, an infinite ways of doing this. I just came up with one (rather verbose admittedly)

#### Verbose solution:

```
const arr = [
  {
    red_team: {
      count: 2,
      money: 3000,
    },
    blue_team: {
      count: 10,
      money: 100000,
    },
  },
  {
    red_team: {
      count: 1,
      money: 1000,
    },
    blue_team: {
      count: 100,
      money: 200000,
    },
  }
];

function sumByKeyAndProperty(arr, key, property){
  let sum = 0
  arr.forEach((obj) => {
    sum+=obj[key][property]
  })
  return sum
}

returnObj = {
  red_team: {
    count: sumByKeyAndProperty(arr, 'red_team', 'count'),
    money: sumByKeyAndProperty(arr, 'red_team', 'money'),
  },
  blue_team: {
    count: sumByKeyAndProperty(arr, 'blue_team', 'count'),
    money: sumByKeyAndProperty(arr, 'blue_team', 'money'),
  }
}

console.log(returnObj)
```